# iPhone graph of - Average sleep per week or month

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, health.app

I am trying to track my sleep, currently using Pillow.  But there is a lot of variation in my sleep per night. I’m looking for an app that displays a graph of the average hours of sleep per night for a week so I can more easily see how the average is changing over weeks and months.

Something like a weeklong rolling avg as a  smoothing function on top of what Pillow and the Apple Health apps give you out of the box.

Does anyone know of an app with a graph like this?

Comment: Sleep cycle gives an average over a week, 5 weeks, 5 months and as long as you have sleep cycle data

Answer (score 1):

Autosleep works for me really well the last 6 months.

- AutoSleep Tracker for Watch by Tantsissa https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosleep-tracker-for-watch/id1164801111?mt=8

I’m much more inclined to get the best data wearing my watch at night, but it does work well if you use charging your phone as proxy for when you lie down and when you get up. Of course you can manually start and stop your rest periods, but for me that is the last hint I want to do before and after resting.